# Does running an example code from Swift learning resources really require enrolling in Mac developer program?

Tags: macos, swift, xcode6

... or am I doing something wrong? (*Yep. I was. Feel free to skip to the Update section.*) I've read a couple of quickstart posts and was ready to dive into the "amazingly new language", so I visited https://developer.apple.com/swift/resources/ in order to get my hands on some nifty tutorials and what did I get? I downloaded a *Lister* XCode project, opened it, switched build target to *My Mac*, started the build and... all I got was a couple of windows telling me to become a developer for 99 bucks.

I'm pretty new to all this locked-in-itself Mac/OS X/whatever ecosystem and, coming here from mostly free and painful Linux, I find these little things really repulsive, so I hope that this problem is really in my head and I *can* run exemplary code without paying $99.

If this is an off-topic question, please point me in the right direction (except for the case when you think I should crawl into some dark corner and cry about how hard thing in real life are).

*Update.* This issue seems to have a happy ending. As some of you mentioned in the comment section and in your answers, I should've disable the code signing feature for the project in order to build and run it. The confusion was all mine when I *did disable* the signing procedure for the sub-projects that interested me (ListerOSX and its dependencies), but as it turned out, in order to successfully compile and launch the project, one also should disable signing for *all* the sub-projects (targets, whatever). E.g. if you are launching ListerOSX, make sure you've disabled signing for Lister Watch app etc.

Seeing as this was at least a bit subtle for me, of whom you might say 'Mac development newbie', I'd still ask you not to close the question but rather leave it open: should anyone else stumble into the same problem, my story might actually help.

Comment: You may build and run, but to deploy you have to pay the gatekeeper.  All this is documented on Apple's website, which I recommend you visit along with StackExchange::Programmers if ambiguities remain.

Comment: That doesn't seem right to me. Could you post screenshots of the windows?

Comment: Remove all "Code Signing" settings from all targets. Then you should be able to compile and run locally.

Comment: @SevenBits, here's a couple of screenshots: https://imgur.com/a/1DiHD. As I mentioned, there is a large probability that I'm just a newbie and miss something simple, in which case I'd be grateful if you point that missed thing to me.

Comment: @MartinR, thank you! I'll give it a try and update my post in case of success :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent versions of Mac OS X will not allow software to run unless it is signed by a developer, or the user is technically savvy enough to bypass gatekeeper (which is not very hard. Just right click on the app and select "open", and then the unsigned software will run).

This is an attempt by Apple to block malware distribution. If malware is not signed, then users who are likely to fall for malware will not know how to make it run. If malware is signed, then Apple can can pass the signature (and associated contact details) to the FBI who will try to organise a lengthy jail term.

What this means for you, as a developer, is you need to either get a certificate or accept that your software will only run with gatekeeper turned off.

The normal mac developer program is $99/year and includes a whole bunch of stuff that makes it well worth the price. However there is a free "Developer ID" membership level that only gives you the ability to sign your apps.

So, you've got three options:

- sign up for a free developer account and sign with that
- sign up for a paid account
- don't sign your code and accept that it will not pass gatekeeper. just disable code signing in your "release" builds. It's already disabled by default in "debug" builds.

Comment: He can NOT sign an app with a free developer ID

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus since when? Maybe it's changed? I can only find old articles about the free developer id. Also, you can self sign your code which is obviously free — we're doing that with Sequel Pro. GateKeeper lets us through.

Comment: Ah, I see now. The reason I ranted so much was actually because I haven't had a chance to systematically read some introductory articles about this whole stuff. I've managed to fix the issue, so I'll update the post and accept your answer since it helped me to figure things out. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable code signing via on all targets in the project settings. Code signing with an official Apple certificate requires a paid account. You can still sign your code to identify yourself as the author, but it will not pass Gatekeeper automatically and you will not be able to sign directly from Xcode.

Comment: So, basically, I was correct in my assumption that it's not possible for a person not willing to pay the price just to try and have a chance to decide if the language is fit for him to the full extent? Is there any way to work with the frameworks provided by Apple without paying? I mean, if I like them, I'll pay - $100 is no big deal if you plan to actually *work* and get results from the thing, but just to have a glance? That't no way to treat a newbie. (IMO)

Comment: Code signing requires a paid account, as it's part of deploying to the App Store. But you should be able to disable code signing on the example project and run it without.

Comment: @cdshines No, you were not correct. You can write code and deploy all that you want - you only need to pay if you want to publish on the Mac App Store and have apps that automatically pass Gatekeeper.

Comment: This is completely wrong. Code Signing does not require a paid account.

Comment: @SevenBits yes I saw your edit. Code signing does not require a paid account.

Comment: @AbhiBeckert You can't get a certificate from Apple that let's your app bypass Gatekeeper unless you have a paid account. That is my understanding.